# This error appears when I try to add the path to the Android SDK in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I keep seeing a error whenever I try to to add the path to the Android SDK in Unity

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILwTQ.png)
the error message is `Invalid Android SDK directory`.

I tried to change the folder arrangement to match the expected path in the error, but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems like you picked a file, just go inside the SDK folder/directory and hit Ok. It should be the one above cmdline-tools

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Planning on reinstalling Unity from Unity Hub to get the files.

Comment: Well, you can download the Android SDK separately as it's used for pure Android development as well. I think they're using the same SDK I use for Android Studio, and I think I did point Unity to my existing SDK before. Those SDKs are quite huge, so I recommend that you don't download multiple times

Comment: can i have download link